# Was my "not an answer flag" for this answer not warranted?

Tags: discussion, flagging, moderation

I recently flagged [this answer](https://superuser.com/revisions/819021/1)(The link is to the revision it was in when I flagged it) as "not an answer", and had my flagged marked invalid.

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

The reason I flagged the post wasn't becuase of some "technical inaccuracies", but becuase it didn't address the [question](https://superuser.com/q/431079/360392) at all, Instead, it was addressed to a side question asked in a comment. It really has nothing to do with the original problem.

Am I misunderstanding when this flag should be used? Would another flag have been more appropriate? Or did the mod who invalidated my flag not that the "answer" was directed at a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right; the post appears to be addressing the comment from Xero, but it's only evident looking at the [first revision](https://superuser.com/posts/819021/revisions) which was the version you had flagged, but not the one visible to the moderator handling the flag.

[image]

On first sight it really looks like it's a separate answer that could use some user's help to be improved (not necessarily a mod though, hence the declined flag).

But anyway, the formatting is horrible. It is plagiarized, the OP admitted they didn't really care about it, and it's unlikely to be salvaged. So I deleted it after all.

Comment: Strange. the first revision is what I was looking at when I clicked "flag". Since it was deleted (and I can't see deleted posts) I can't check when it revised. I suppose it is possible the edit came in right before I flagged, and I didn't refresh to see the new edit. Otherwise there may be some sort of bug.

Comment: I added a screenshot. You're right, you flagged it *before* it was edited to remove the direct mention.

Comment: Does the flag review UI not clearly show which revision the flag was made on? I'd make a feature request, but not being a mod, I don't know enough about the interface to know what to recommend.

Comment: No, it doesn't say that. You just see the latest revision. Of course as a moderator you *should* check, but sometimes we handle lots of flags at once...